# Correct use of SelectLayerByAttribute_management in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

What are displayed in the `tableName` are polygon features in a geodatabase. I would like for each row in a loop to take each row `TableName` and apply the sql query from the `sqlstring` field and make the feature according to that query that corresponds.

```
    qname   TheTableName SqlString
0   shp_q1  AST_A        SELECT ...
1   shp_q2  AST_B        SELECT ...
2   shp_q3  AST_PX       SELECT ...
```

I want to make a new feature polygon according to what the query describes, named as the `qname` column is named in that row.

---

Example: Take the `AST_A` feature polygon, apply the query that it has in the `SqlString` column and make a new feature polygon based on that query called `shp_q1`

Here I access the columns that are needed:

```
datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("*")
for dataset in datasetList:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["TheTableName","SqlString"]) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            query = row[1] #to access the query part of the row
                arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(row[0], "NEW_SELECTION", query)
```

`row[0]` is the '`TheTableName`' column and `row[1]` is the `SqlString` column.

How should I change the `SelectLayerByAttribute_management` function parameters to achieve that?

Comment: You want to output new feature classes based on your condition or what is the step after the selection?

Comment: Yes, new outputs that will show what the query describes that will be named like the `qname` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Select_analysis, it will output a feature class based on a Query:

```
import arcpy, os

table_workspace = r'C:\someFolderOrDatabase'
polygon_feature_database = r'C:\someDataBase.gdb'
shapefile_output_folder = r'C:\someFolder'

arcpy.env.workspace = table_workspace
tableList = [os.path.join(table_workspace, table) for table in arcpy.ListTables("*")]

arcpy.env.workspace = polygon_feature_database
for table in tableList:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ["qname","TheTableName","SqlString"]) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            query = row[2]
            arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=row[1], out_feature_class=os.path.join(shapefile_output_folder,row[0]+'.shp'),where_clause=query)
```

If you want to save output to a file geodatabase:

```
...
shapefile_output_folder = r'C:\someOutputDatabase.gdb'
...
... out_feature_class=os.path.join(shapefile_output_folder,row[0])...
```

Comment: I didn't know about select analysis.Very creative approach. thanks. I will study it for a moment.

Comment: Can you please add also an alternative way to export the results in the geodatabase itself and not folder.

Comment: Just change `shapefile_output_folder = r'C:\someFolder'` to point at a database and remove `+'.shp'`

Comment: And at the last line put this: out_feature_class=os.path.join(gdb_path,row[0]?

Comment: `out_feature_class=os.path.join(shapefile_output_folder,row[0])`

Comment: I have a question regarding the Select analysis. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/299706/select-analysis-in-arcpy-correct-format-of-query . Feel free to check it out. Thanks