# Select_analysis in ArcPy gives ERROR 000358?

Tags: arcpy, select, error-000358

Trying to learn how to use `Select_analysis` but the queries cause the

> ERROR 000358: Invalid expression.

Piece of code:

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features='test1',
                out_feature_class=os.path.join(r'C:\Users\users\Desktop\05\Project1.gdb',
                 'WACDE'),where_clause="Select test1.KA FROM test1 WHERE test1.NUM = '12'")
```

What is the correct form?

Comment: What is your data source? SQL Server, shapefile, PostgreSQL, File Geodatabase, etc?  Your datasource will dictate how you communicate with it via SQL statements.  See [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/sql-reference-for-elements-used-in-query-expressions.htm#GUID-68D21843-5274-4AF4-B7F3-165892232A43).

Comment: The `where_clause` parameter accepts ***only*** a WHERE clause (with or without the WHERE). There are a number of examples of correct `Select_analysis` usage in the documentation.

Comment: it's a geodatabse in ArcMap.

Comment: @Vince So is there any way to accept a normal select statement as we would in a normal database or they always have to be like the answer below?

Comment: If it was an Enterprise database, then you could use `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute`, but file database doesn't have a backend SQL engine. You need to parse the SELECT statement elements and  drop them into their respective parameters.

Comment: That's what I was asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\users\Desktop\05\Project1.gdb'
in_features = 'test1'
out_feature_class = 'WACDE'
where_clause = "NUM = '12'"
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features , out_feature_class , where_clause)
```

Check this out, it should work. I assumed your column is named **NUM**.
Let me know if that was your goal to achieve.

Comment: I know this works the problem is that I have a column full of select statements and I will need to use them as full sql queries like in a database. Can you tell me how to make it work with the query above?I am upvoting for the effort though

Comment: Just add some more info about your problem, ex. some screenshots of that table.

Comment: To explain, the select query I have in the question is an alternative way to do what you did.The thing is that the queries have the first form (select ... from .. where). How can I make it process queries in that form, just like in a database?using Select_analysis? Thanks

Comment: Is this a column as an attribute in a shapefile or featureclass, or in a CSV table, or some other data source? When you read the input, you should be able to break it up using split in arcpy, for example `whereclause = sqlquery.split("WHERE ")[-1]`

Comment: it's a geodatabse in ArcMap. Is there a way to use a normal select statement as we would in a database? Or it has to be typed like in the answer?

Comment: If I want to keep certain columns  at the end how can I do it?

Comment: You want to extract selection? If yes --> then use Copy Features.

Comment: I mean what you did there but also choose what columns from `test1` to exist at the output.